# Corda node fail to start when connected to Oracle database

Tags: corda

I am using

- Corda Enterprise: 4.5
- Token-sdk : 1.0
- Oracle driver : ojdbc7.jar

Getting following error

> Exception during node startup: Incompatible schema change detected.
> Please run the node with database.initialiseSchema=true. Reason:
> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column
> [token_class] in table [schem.fungible_token]; found [nvarchar
> (Types#NVARCHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]

We tried solution 2 from https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/issues/150 however database-manager-tool is not loading fungible-token-schema-v2.changelog-master.xml file . We also tried to upgrade Token SDK to 1.1 however Corda node failed to start. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Oracle drivers version looks bad. Also, Corda is not patched version. If you cannot use 4.7, try 4.5.2 - check with support the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

As @wawrzek suggested, this looks like a driver issue. It might be that there's a schema migration that didn't work as well.

It's not super clear just based on this message which it could be.

One last note is that if you've got corda enterprise then I recommend pinging support as they should be able to help you out more with these kinds of specific issues.